# Normal operator equal to its norm and that of its adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators, normal-operator

I am coming up with this equality over and over again in Linear ALgebra Done Right by Axler and I cant seem to derive it. I've tried looking up something similar here, the closest I've got is this:[Normal operator iff norm on v equivalent to that of adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309734/normal-operator-iff-norm-on-v-equivalent-to-that-of-adjoint) , but the equality is only stated. I understand both $TT^*$ and
$T^*T$ are self-adjoint, as well as T normal but I don't see how this implies $\langle TT^*v,v\rangle = \langle T^*v,T^*v\rangle$, and $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle = \langle Tv,Tv\rangle$

Comment: The fundamental (indeed, defining) property of the adjoint is the formula $\langle Tv,w\rangle = \langle v,T^*w\rangle$.

Comment: To amplify @TedShifrin's comment: The two equations you asked about have nothing to do with normality of $T$ or self-adjointness of $T^*T$ and $TT^*$. They are just special cases of the definition of "adjoint".

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309734/977780)

Comment: Okay thanks! I think I get it now. These equalities are variants of the self-adjoint definition, in which we are just substituting $w$ in $\langle Tv,w \rangle$ = $\langle v,T^*w\rangle$ by $Tv$ and $v$ by $T^*v$ in the other case. These two expressions happen to be equal iff the operator is normal.